# DownThemAll API object DTA no more available to Firefox Extension Development?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I wrote a Firefox plugin a while ago that collected some links from a website and sent them to DownThemAll via the global dta object.

Now with the latest upgrade of DownThemAll it seems this object is no more available. Does anybody know of the API Change in DownThemAll?

My call to DTA so far was DTA.sendLinksToManager(window, true, fileList);
(The DTA object was globally available to the Firefox Extension javascript)

Comment: You will probably get more knowledgeable responses by asking on their [support site](http://www.downthemall.net/howto/faq/#faq5), via the info from their [contacts page](http://www.downthemall.net/main/contacts/), or through their bug reporting process. Alternately, you can look at their [source code](http://www.downthemall.net/development/source-code/). If you're not talking about the *most* recent update, but are actually talking about a difference between ver. 2 and ver. 3: They changed from overlay to bootstrapped. This could have easily resulted in the loss or change of the `DTA` object.

Comment: Another time, you are probably better off first trying to contact the add-on developers directly using the links for "Add-on home page", "Support site", or "Support email" which, if configured by the add-on developer, are provided on the right site of the [AMO add-on page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) just to the right of "About this Add-on" and below the screenshots. These modes of contact should result in you getting in touch with people that have direct knowledge about the add-on (the developers, or whoever the developers have delegated such contact).

Comment: thank you! Actually I did contact their support, but since it could take long till they answer, I tought trying to contact other developers could be worth a try.